# CIVI Event setup is blank

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I would like to set up an event, but every time we try (multiple different days, different browsers, different staff members on different networks) the window opens up completely blank.

Screenshot #1: Menu navigation Events> New Event
[image]
Screenshot #2: Menu navigation Events> Manage Events > Add Event
[image]

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I see you're on 5.34 - your url looks wrong. See https://civicrm.org/blog/kcristiano/civicrm-526-and-wordpress-important-notice where there was a change in 5.26.